# How to find most frequent list within a list - Python

Tags: python, list, iterator

For example, how would you find the most occurred list within a list of lists and appropriate counts. Counter from collections doesn't seem to accept lists as elements.

```
my_list = [[10, 2, 14], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 4], [10, 2, 14]]
# most frequent list: ([10, 2, 14], 2)
```

Comment: for the list `[[10, 2, 14], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 4], [2, 10, 14]]` should also the output be `([10, 2, 14], 2)`?

Comment: No, the order of the sub-lists would be important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not accept mutable elements, but for simple lists you can convert it to tuples:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = [[10, 2, 14], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 4], [10, 2, 14]]

Counter(tuple(i) for i in my_list).most_common()
```

you have to convert the most common element back to a list of course.